# Dask - Possible to assign dask_key_name to dask dataframe tasks?

Tags: dask, dask-distributed, dask-delayed

In the course of debugging issues, I've found it hard to decipher exactly which tasks are causing problems.  I've used the 'dask_key_name' kwarg successfully in delayed tasks to assign a human-readable name to the key for those delayed tasks (based on the documentation here: https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/delayed-api.html).  I've tried to do the following in the hopes that it would do the same for the read_parquet tasks, but it appears it still uses a hashed value to create the key (e.g., ('read-parquet-ed9e6c4c474e851e176e7eafb8753490', 5)).

```
item = 'custom_string'
self.all_pfs_dict['read'][item] = dd.read_parquet(item_to_read, index=False, gather_statistics=False, dask_key_name=item + '-read')
```

Am I doing something wrong or is there an alternative way to name dask dataframe tasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to rename dataframe tasks like this today.

Answer (score 0):

I have previously had a similar question, but it does not seem to support such a thing except [`from_pandas()`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.from_pandas) method.

`from_pandas()` has the `name` parameter to [set name](https://github.com/dask/dask/blob/8254115cb312cec907f6201ee904068ddb64f687/dask/dataframe/io/io.py#L181), but others like [`read_parquet()`](https://github.com/dask/dask/blob/8254115cb312cec907f6201ee904068ddb64f687/dask/dataframe/io/parquet.py#L211) don't.

So if you want to do it, you need to change the Dask code linked above.